# Ошибка: «Unresolved external 'std::tr1::_Random_device()'»

Tags: c++, windows, c++builder, radstudio

При попытке скомпилировать следующий исходный код:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::tr1::random_device rd;
    std::tr1::mt19937 rng(rd());
    std::tr1::uniform_int<int> uni(0,20);
    std::cout<<uni(rng)<<std::endl;
}
```

командрой `bcc32.exe t.cpp` получаю такую ошибку:

```
Turbo Incremental Link 6.51 Copyright (c) 1997-2013 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
Error: Unresolved external 'std::tr1::_Random_device()' referenced from <...>\T.OBJ
Error: Unable to perform link
```

Компилятор версии 6.70.4983.33517 из RAD Studio XE5

Как исправить эту ошибку? Может, нужно подключить какую-то библиотеку?

Comment: А оно у вас вообще компилируется?... `std::tr1::mt19937 rng(rd);` - вот это? Вроде ж надо `std::tr1::mt19937 rng(rd());`. И еще - что, Borland все еще держит это все в `tr1`, не просто в `std`? Если удалить `::tr1`, что у вас получается?

Comment: @Harry Да, там должно быть `rd()`, сейчас исправлю. Но ошибка остаётся, конечно. Без `tr1` будет что-то вроде `Error E2316 t.cpp 5: 'random_device' is not a member of 'std' in function main()`